# Mouseout and mousedown conflict

Tags: jquery, background, contextmenu, mousehover

I want to in `table` if user put mouse over each row that row colored with animate and when mouse out then row's color return to its default. but if user right click on row ,that row be red until click on context menu .

I tried this code but when user right click and want select a menu item ,red row return to default but I want to row be red until click(select):

```
$(function () {
$('.users').contextMenu({
    selector: 'tr',
    callback: function (key, options) {
        if (key == 'delete') {
            if (confirm(" Are you sure?")) {
                $.post("../Actions/Delete.ashx", { type: "user", id: $(this).attr('id') });
                $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#FF80FF' }, 1000);
            }
        }

    },
    items: {
        "edit": { name: "edit" },
        "delete": { name: "delete" }
    }
});
$('tr').mouseover(function () {
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
    ({ backgroundColor: "#80FF00" }, 300);
});

$('tr').mouseout(function () {
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
    ({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 300);
});
$('tr').mousedown(function (event) {
    if (event.which==3) {
        $('td', this).animate
    ({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 300);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: What about building in a check on background color? If it's red don't switch back to the default color. Or mark the row somehow and check for it in the `mouseout` event.

Comment: @netiul good idea! I'm now working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that right clicked with `clicked` flag:

```
$(function () {
var clicked=false;
$('.users').contextMenu({
    selector: 'tr',
    callback: function (key, options) {
        if (key == 'delete') {
            if (confirm(" Are you sure?")) {
                $.post("../Actions/Delete.ashx", { type: "user", id: $(this).attr('id') });

                $(this).animate({ backgroundColor: '#FF80FF' }, 1000);
            }
        clicked=false;
        }

    },
    items: {
        "edit": { name: "edit" },
        "delete": { name: "delete" }
    }
});
$('tr').mouseover(function () {
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
    ({ backgroundColor: "#80FF00" }, 300);
});

$('tr').mouseout(function () {
    if(!clicked){
    $('td', this).stop(true, true).animate
    ({ backgroundColor: "white" }, 300);
}
});
$('tr').mousedown(function (event) {
    if (event.which==3) {
        clicked=true;
        $('td', this).animate
    ({ backgroundColor: "red" }, 300);
    }
});
});
```